parse json formatted string in Impala
I have a table with multiple columns, one of which is a json formatted string. Sample data is shown below. The name of the column is json_data

{"A":{"B":"b","C":"c","D":{"E":"e","F":"f"}}}

I am trying the below query in Impala and only seeing nulls.
> select get_json_object(json_data,"$.D.F") as value, json_data from
> mytable;

the result of the query only shows NULLs. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to make it right?
I am trying to extract the values of each of the keys present in the json object. In the SQL above, the output I am expecting to see is 'f'.

If you want to extract the key "F" value from the nested JSON object, use the json_extract().
Try this query:
SELECT json_extract(json_data, '$.A.D.F') as value, json_data FROM mytable;

